# Debian Wheezy 7.7.0 x86 - won't compile anything

Tags: debian, compile, reset

Yesterday I installed Debian Wheezy 7.7.00-netinst and everything was fine until the moment I decided to compile libtorrent-0.13.4.
I do:

```
./configure
```

the checkings start for about 2 seconds and the whole system just resets (it's headless, but I attached a monitor and the screen first goes gray and then I see the BIOS POST)..
Then I tried to compile wget, curl and again, with the same results.

After that I decided to try to push the system to its limits

```
stress -c 3 -m 1200M
```

for about 15 minutes and nothing happened other than the system get a little hot.

Today, I reinstalled the whole system and installed Debian Wheezy 7.7.00-CD 1.
Again, the same thing happens.

Comment: I know you've run `stress`, but this still smell like bad RAM to me. Can you give `memtest86+` or the like a shot?

Comment: Oh, yes, of course my first thoughts was for the RAM, I changed it, forgot to write this..
Now I installed rtorrent from repo, will try to use the server like this, if it continues to fail, I think I will try with CentOS.